# Install ServiceStack Web Service Framework via NuGet then got an exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, servicestack

The exception is strange, seems I missing sth. Any ideas?

> Locating source for 'C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack.FluentValidation.Mvc3\Mvc\FunqControllerFactory.cs'. Checksum: MD5 {eb 6 8b dc fb 97 cb 8 2b 74 bc 37 37 79 7b f8}
>   The file 'C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack.FluentValidation.Mvc3\Mvc\FunqControllerFactory.cs' does not exist.
>   Looking in script documents for 'C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack.FluentValidation.Mvc3\Mvc\FunqControllerFactory.cs'...
>   Looking in the projects for 'C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack.FluentValidation.Mvc3\Mvc\FunqControllerFactory.cs'.
>   The file was not found in a project.
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\'...
>   The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack.FluentValidation.Mvc3\Mvc\FunqControllerFactory.cs.
>   The debugger could not locate the source file 'C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack.FluentValidation.Mvc3\Mvc\FunqControllerFactory.cs'.

Comment: You've got the latest version on NuGet? Is this only a problem when trying to debug?

Comment: Yes. I reinstall the latest Nuget, then I created an empty MVC3 project,then run the install in Nuget. This is only issue I got so far, as I could not move any more. I will try this thing on my machine at home anyway .

Comment: Think I find the solution myself. If you install the servicestack through nuget,you need to comment out the original routs.MapRoute in Global.ascx.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think I find the solution myself.
If you install the servicestack to a MVC3 project through nuget,you need to comment out the original routs.MapRoute in Global.ascx.cs

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //routes.MapRoute(
        //    "Default", // Route name
        //    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        //    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        //);

        routes.IgnoreRoute("api/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" }); //Prevent exceptions for favicon

    }
```

Comment: What you did here is not a good solution to your problem. Instead of commenting out default MVC route, you should move your ignore route statements before the default one. It is not by accident that the initial ignore statement comes first in the register routes method.

Comment: You are right. At that time, i　was just doing a hack work and didnt test the defualt MVC things. Thanks